# Special characters on file path:. Slash symbol

Tags: c#, pdf, filestream, slash, pdf-writer

I work with files. And use code like this:

```
 PdfWriter.GetInstance(newFile, new FileStream(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageFolder"] + "\\" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "\\fnp\\request_" + myVariable+ "_l" + confirmLevel.ToString() + ".pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create));
```

This line generates my file's full path. For example, if `myVariable="0001"` then it is OK. So newFile's full path will be something like, say, StorageFolder\2016\fnp\request_0001_l2.pdf.  But I want to assign myVariable value  like `myVariable = "0001/16"`. Then **PdfWriter.GetInstance**  method tries to create path like StorageFolder\2016\fnp\request_0001\16_l2.pdf. But I need it to create StorageFolder\2016\fnp\request_0001/16_l2.pdf.

How can I manage it?

Comment: I take it you arent running under windows?? either way try entering the \ as \\

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to create a folder named `request_0001` and then place the file `16_l2.pdf` inside, or do you want to create a file named `request_0001/16_l2.pdf` ?

Comment: I use it under Windows system. @BugFinder.

Comment: I want create a file named  request_0001/16_l2.pdf  @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: You can't. '/' is not a legal character in a foldername or filename on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't.

The `/` character is not legal in foldernames or filenames on Windows.

You will have to pick another character instead, one that is legal.

You can read more about these things in this [MSDN Article: Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), except for the following reserved characters:
>   `<` (less than)
>   `>` (greater than)
>   `:` (colon)
>   `"` (double quote)
>   `/` (forward slash)
>   `\` (backslash)
>   `|` (vertical bar or pipe)
>   `?` (question mark)
>   `*` (asterisk)
>   + some other details

Comment: Thank you. I'll take into consideration.